# Python TypeHint: What Return Type to use for the factory methods?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Here is my code snippet. I wonder what return type to use for the `create` classmethod of both factory classes. I would like to avoid using `Union[Model1, Model2]` if it's possible.

```
T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound="BaseModel")


@dataclass
class BaseModel(object):
    pass


@dataclass
class Model1(BaseModel):
    pass


@dataclass
class Model2(BaseModel):
    pass


class ModelFactory(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def create(cls) -> T:
        pass


class Model1Factory(ModelFactory):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls) -> T:
        return Model1()


class Model2Factory(ModelFactory):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls) -> T:
        return Model2()

m1factory = Model1Factory()
m1 = m1factory.create()
```

The error I am getting from mypy:

```
type_hint.child_class_return_self.2.py:32: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Model1", expected "T")
type_hint.child_class_return_self.2.py:37: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Model2", expected "T")
type_hint.child_class_return_self.2.py:41: error: Need type annotation for 'm1'
```

Comment: `Model1Factor` should return `Model1`, not `T`, same as `Model2Factory` with `Model2`. ModelFactory can just return `T`, although, why on earth you are doing this sort of thing in Python I cannot imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to incorporate `Generic` into the equation so that `mypy` can accept different return types:

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound="BaseModel")


@dataclass
class BaseModel(object):
    pass


@dataclass
class Model1(BaseModel):
    pass


@dataclass
class Model2(BaseModel):
    pass


class ModelFactory(Generic[T], ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def create(cls) -> T:
        pass


class Model1Factory(ModelFactory[Model1]):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls) -> Model1:
        return Model1()


class Model2Factory(ModelFactory[Model2]):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls) -> Model2:
        return Model2()


m1factory = Model1Factory()
m1 = m1factory.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [mypy cheat sheet](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html) you should go for `Union[Model1, Model2]`, but if it's something you want to avoid, the next best candidate is `Any` type.